# How to create custom input component with validation in Angular14?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-validation, controlvalueaccessor, angular-controlvalueaccessor

I want to create custom component for input text but I don't know how can I bind validation of each input field to custom component. Is there any way to set errors of each field as array of objects like below

```
<app-custom-input
          formControlName="username"
          label="Username"
          [errors]="[
          { type: 'required', message: 'is required' },
          { type: 'minlength', message: 'min length error' }
        ]"
        ></app-custom-input>
```

In fact, I want to write reusable components that have different validations, for example, one field is required and another field has a length condition.

[stackblitz.io](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-custom-input-controlvalueaccessor-yyincy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Haven't done it myself, but I think [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) is specifically designed for these scenarios. It supports more advanced stuff than the classic html validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step.

When we make a custom form control with validate the function validate should return or an object or null -if no errors-.

```
  public validate(c: FormControl) {
    const errors: any[] = [];
    if (!this.control) this.control = c;

    this.errors &&
      this.errors.forEach((error) => {
        if (error.type == 'required') {
          if (!c.value) {
            errors.push({ required: true, message: error.message });
          }
        }
      });
    return errors.length ? { error: errors } : null;
  }
```

See that return an object with an unique property "error" that is an array of errors.

This error is an error **not** of the inner control -you input inside the custom-input- else the `FormControl` declared in "parent". So, to iterate over this error inside the custom form control we need "get it".

Generally you use the constructor

```
constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl){
  if (this.ngControl != null) {
     this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }
}
```

But, as we have a validate function simply we declare, and give value to it in validate function

```
  control!: AbstractControl;

  public validate(c: FormControl) {
    if (!this.control) this.control = c;
    ...rest of the code..
  }
```

The last is iterate over this errors

```
<ng-container *ngIf="control?.touched || control?.dirty">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let error of control?.errors?.error">
    <div class="error-text">
      {{ error.message }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-custom-input-controlvalueaccessor-djcp83?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: See that you needn't add the `validators` to your `FormControls`

In your code:

```
registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    username: [''],
    password: [''],
  });
```

**update** to only send if reuired we need use some like

```
  public validate(c: FormControl) {
    const errors: any[] = [];
    if (!this.control) this.control = c;
cons errorRequired==!c.value && this.errors?this.errors.find(x=>x=='required'):null
 if (errorRequired)
     return [{required:true,message:errorRequired.message}]
    
    this.errors &&
      this.errors.forEach((error) => {
        if (error.type == 'required') {
          if (!c.value) {
            errors.push({ required: true, message: error.message });
          }
        }
      });
    return errors.length ? { error: errors } : null;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for required validation, but what should I do for use customer validators like min length? please check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-custom-input-controlvalueaccessor-kdcjjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @user21636825, in the function válidamente, inside the loop of errores, chech if error.type=='minlength' add a new object to the array errors and so. Note: generally if the error is required you should not add new error.

Comment: how can I prevent other errors when I get required?

Comment: When compare if required, if not fullfilled, instead of push, use `errors=[{required: true, message: error.message }];return;`

Comment: Sorry, you're in a fooreach, so you can not use return. You need, before the foreach, ask about `if (errors && errors.find(x=>x.type=='required')` I just update que answer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the previous method worked correctly
I am trying the other methods you mentioned to create a custom component, but I ran into an error that I asked in another post, is it possible, please check it too. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76017439/type-abstractcontrolany-any-null-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-f)